# SwipeItem in Maui is clicked without interaction

Tags: c#, maui

In my `MAUI` application, I have a `CollectionView` where I display some values (in the screenshot below *Test1* for example).

Like in the `ListView`, I want to allow the users to swipe to show a menu and then select an option. In order to do that, I read this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data). So, I placed in a `SwipeView` in the `DataTemplate` of the `CollectionView`. Here is the code (I omitted the content of the `Grid`):

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionWord" ItemsSource="{Binding WordGroups}" 
                    IsGrouped="true" Grid.Row="2"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    SelectionMode="Single" 
                    SelectionChanged="collectionWord_SelectionChanged">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <SwipeItems>
                        <SwipeItem x:Name="swEdit" Text="Edit" 
                                   BackgroundColor="White" 
                                   Clicked="swEdit_Clicked">
                            <SwipeItem.IconImageSource>
                                <FontImageSource 
                                    Glyph="{x:Static hlp:FontAwesomeIcons.Pencil}"
                                    Color="Black"
                                    FontFamily="FAS" Size="44" />
                            </SwipeItem.IconImageSource>
                        </SwipeItem>
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.RightItems>
                <Grid>
                    <!-- -->
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The design is what I expected but the behaviours is not. When I swipe an item, you can see the `SwipeItem` but also immediately the item is clicked. Here the example

[image]

I don't have this behaviour with a `ListView`. Is there a way to fix it?

### Update

I ran the app in my iMac in a simulator. The simulator runs for iPhone 15 iOS 17.0. In the same application, a `ListView` is working as I expected but the `CollectionView` freezes the app and after few seconds it crashes. As a side note, the splashscreen is completely black.

The `CollectionView` is highlighed (in grey but I don't know why) and after few seconds, the app crashes.

[image]

Here the error

[image]

On the iMac I also ran the app to an Android Emulator Pixel 5 API 31. If I swipe the finger on the mouse or drag the item to see the context menu, in both cases is like I click the item.

Comment: `but also immediately the item is clicked. Here the example` I noticed that the SwipeView  was closed after you touched the other part of the SwipeView instead of the `Edit` option.   That's the desired action of the Maui. And based on your code, I created a demo and the code works properly on my side.

Comment: Maybe the screenshot is not clear but I swipe the item and I don't click any element. How I swipe without clicking anything, the element fires the `Clicked` event.

Comment: Could you please post more code snippets so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?